# Can I store a reference to an variable in an object?

Tags: c#, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing a reference to an object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760087/storing-a-reference-to-an-object-in-c)

Is there a way to store a reference in a class object? Something like:

```
public class X
{
  public X(ref int i)
  {
    _t = i;
  }

  public void f(int ii)
  {
    _i = ii;
  }

  private int ref _i;
}

// ...
int i = 0;
X x = new X(ref i);
x.f(42);
// i is now 42
```

In C++ I'd do this with pointers or references.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Rafał: I thought I did. I want a class object to reference an object stored elsewhere, so that changes inflicted by class member functions are reflected in this outside object.

Comment: *See Also [.net - Storing a reference to an C# object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760087/storing-a-reference-to-an-object-in-c)*

Comment: @Brad: Thanks. I guess this is a dupe of that one then. _Voted to close._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with unmanaged code, but there isn't a managed code way to have a reference to a value type.  You'd have to manually box it into some kind of object container and have a reference to that.

Comment: @sbi - isn't that what C++ is for? ;-)  In all seriousness, I think in most designs it is better to have a nice fat object reference to fiddle with even if you start out with a single property - it lets you get in between using a setter property or whatever when you need to, plus you can expand the interface of the referred class to multiple properties without adding additional "by-reference" values.

Comment: I'm bound to do this in C#. I'd love to do C++ instead, believe me. (Just look at the questions I asked and the answers I've given in my profile...)

Comment: @sbi - I know, I was joking - the best I can offer is see if you can expand your design scope a little and see if there are other things this object container of the value type can do and take advantage of the fact that you have to have a reference to a full-blown object.  The variable has to be somewhere - so the instance holding it can implement an interface for updating just that one property.

Comment: Thanks. I think I made the old failure of asking how to get a specific solution working, rather than asking how to solve my problem. `:(` [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464838/temporarily-change-a-variables-value) my actual problem now.