# Temporarily change a variable's value

Tags: c#

In an API implementation I'm currently hacking on, there's the need to repeatedly change some variables temporarily, before doing some task, and change them back after the task is done to whatever they were before.

The current code looks like this:

```
var _oldValue = _variable;
_variable = tempValue;
try
{
  doIt();
}
finally
{
  _variable = oldValue;
}
```

Doing this a lot is annoying, ugly, hard to maintain, and buries the actual algorithms under a lot of clutter that's just implementation artifacts.

In C++, I would make a class which stores the old value somewhere during construction, and restores it in its destructor:

```
{
  temp_value tmp(variable_, temp_val);
  do_it();
}
```

When trying to do something similar in C# [I failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463666/can-i-store-a-reference-to-an-variable-in-an-object/) because apparently [C# can't store references to other objects in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760087/storing-a-reference-to-an-object-in-c/2760111#2760111).

So what would I have to do in C# to remove that clutter?

P.S.: Feel free to add any other tags you see fit. I failed to come up with any.

Comment: Write a wrapper static method like `DoItWithRestore()` call that everywhere instead of `DoIt()` that ways this clutter is at one place and make sure you comment it so that future readers of the code understand the intention & purpose.

Comment: Any chance you could find an alternative API to do the same task? It sounds like an extremely brittle one.

Comment: Is it not possible to change `doIt()` so that it takes a parameter?

Comment: Can you explain the context more? Are these variables globals? Are the functions such as "doit" all encapsulated in some class? I'm having a hard time getting my head around the larger picture. Why does "doit" need to affect things outside its scope, if you just intend to switch them back afterwards?

Comment: @Dysaster, @Jonas & @jamietre: This is more a framework than an API. You write code that gets loaded into it, and you get called by the framework to process data - a classic plugin architecture. One example of where this is needed is when `doIt()` calls the plugin's code. Some operations plugin writers might want to perform are only allowed in certain contexts, when certain sets of plugin functions are called. So the framework sets the context before calling the plugin, and functions called from the plugin check whether that context is set. There's other applications of this, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not create a method that does it for you, and then pass a Lamda to it?

```
private void SaveGlobalsAndDoSomething(Action doit)
{
    var _oldValue = _variable;
    _variable = tempValue;
    try
    {
        doit();
    }
    finally
    {
        _variable = _oldValue;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
SaveGlobalsAndDoSomething(() => { DoSomething(); });
```

Edit in response to comment:

That `doit` sometimes returns a value isn't a problem. We're not passing `DoSomething` to the method. We're passing `{ DoSomething(); }` to the method.  So you can easily write:

```
int returnValue;
SaveGlobalsAndDoSomething(() => { returnValue = DoSomething(); });
```

Comment: Ugh. It's not exactly pretty, bit that's probably just because I was expecting something else. And I suppose this would indeed work. Given that I can pass per `ref` to functions, I probably could even pass the variable to change to the function, so that I don't have to duplicate it for every such variable.

Comment: Darn. I just discovered that the there are cases were `doIt()` returns something. I suppose I can use generics to specify the return type? But others don't and I somewhat doubt I can us that returning generic function for returning `void`, as I can in C++? That would mean at least two different functions then... And I thought I'd make this generic and put it into the utility namespace.

Comment: Ah, thanks! While they are among my favourite features of C#, it seems I've yet to come to grips with the full power of lambdas...

Answer (score 7):

While I agree with Eric Lippert on ideal solution there are cases when on forced to temporay change state of varable and execute some actions. I.e. there are several examples of such requirement in SharePoint object model, so it is not possible to redesign code to avoid it.

Below is code that can be used to temporary cahnge value and restor it with `using` statement. Use of `using` for such non-release-unmanged-resources purposes is contentios, so use you judgment if such approach works for you:

Usage sample:

```
using(TemporaryChange(true, myValue, v => myValue = v))
{
 // code to run while "myValue" is changed to "true"
}
```

Class:

```
class TemporaryChange<V> : IDisposable
{
    private V original;
    private Action<V> setValue;

    internal TemporaryChange(V value, V currentValue, Action<V> setValue)
    {
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.original = currentValue;
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.setValue(this.original);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, this smells a lot like C++' RAII, so it it has a certain appeal to me. `:)` However, I consider having to spell out something as simple as an assignment a considerable nuisance. Still, this might be as good as it gets with C#. Thanks!

Comment: I had to use "using (new TemporaryChange<bool>(true, myValue, v => myValue = v))" instead

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you are considering doing a variety of horrible, horrible things to solve this problem is indicative that you shouldn't be in this situation in the first place. If you're in a situation where code depends on mutating and then unmutating state then you have a bad design. **Fix the real design problem rather than trying to come up with a clever way to continue using the bad architecture.**

What I do when I'm in this situation is clone my state. Suppose you are doing this:

```
class Frobber
{
    State state;
    ...
    void M()
    {
         ...
         try
         {
             oldstate = state;
             state = newstate;
             this.DoIt();
         }
         finally
         {
             state = oldstate;
         }
    }
```

Instead do this:

```
class Frobber
{
    State state;
    ...
    void M()
    {
         ...
         Frobber newFrobber = new Frobber(newstate);
         newFrobber.DoIt();
         ...
```

**Instead of mutating a variable and changing it back, make a whole new variable**. Throw away the new variable when you're done with it. The old variable doesn't need to be mutated back because it never changed.

Comment: Eric, I learned to value your insights, but please read my comment to the question, where I explain why this is necessary. Also, even if you are right, and the thing could be redesigned to do it the way you suggest (which I can't see ATM), this is a rather big system (the unit tests take more than an hour) that is already in use with several clients, and needs a smooth upgrade path. I can't redesign at will, because those clients have code that needs to compile against this API, and refactoring has to be done incrementally, to not to break too much at once.